# How to avoid two jobs running at the same time in Quartz?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have tritten below code in which I am running two jobs. First with the interval of 10 seconds and the other with the interval of 3 seconds. But ultimately at some point they will execute at the same time. Is there any mechanism to avoid this situation

```
    JobDetail jDetail = new JobDetail("Job1", "group1", MyJob.class);
    CronTrigger crTrigger = new CronTrigger("cronTrigger", "group1", "0/10 * * * * ?");
    sche.scheduleJob(jDetail, crTrigger);

    jDetail = new JobDetail("Job2","group2",MyJob2.class);
    crTrigger = new CronTrigger("cronTrigger2","group2","0/3 * * * * ?");
    sche.scheduleJob(jDetail, crTrigger);
```

Comment: Are you trying to make sure that the job won't run twice within the same JVM or within multiple JVM's? Also, how long does each task take? Are they subsecond, several seconds, a few minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a helper object to make the two jobs synchronized:

```
//In the base class 
public static Object lock = new Object();

//In the first class
public void execute() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        //do stuff
    }
}

//In the second class
public void execute() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Read more about synchronization at: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: but the OP stated that he runs two different classes, this won't solve his situation

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer you are absolutely correct, did not catch that there where to different classes for the job.

Answer (score 3):

Not completely answering your question but this is how you can query for something running in a thread-safe manner:

```
//sched is your org.quartz.Scheduler
        synchronized (sched) {
            JobDetail existingJobDetail = sched.getJobDetail(jobName, jobGroup);
            if (existingJobDetail != null) {
                List<JobExecutionContext> currentlyExecutingJobs = (List<JobExecutionContext>) sched.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
                for (JobExecutionContext jec : currentlyExecutingJobs) {

                    if (existingJobDetail.equals(jec.getJobDetail())) {
                        // This job is currently executing
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: nice idea to use the Scheduler as watch object!

Answer (score 3):

[Configure the Quartz threadpool](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigThreadPool) to have only one thread.

```
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered: true
```

Alternatively, you make your job into a Stateful job (and set isClustered to true), and that shoujld solve your problem.
(Oops, StatefulJob is deprecated; use DisallowConcurrentExecution.)